# Git push with wrong account

Tags: git, github

I have configured two accounts on my computer with two different SSH keys.

I did not configure a global user for git, because I want git to use different authors (for push, commit, etc) according to the directory I'm in.

This is my `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[includeIf "gitdir:~/Project1/*"]
        path = ~/Project1/.gitconfig
[includeIf "gitdir:~/Project2/*"]
        path = ~/Project2/.gitconfig
```

these are my `~/Project1/.gitconfig` and `~/Project2/.gitconfig`:

```
[user]
    name = user1
    email = mail1@mail1.com
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@github-1:author/repo.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

```
[user]
    name = user2
    email = mail2@mail2.com
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@github-2:author/repo.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

and this is my `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host github-1
        HostName github.com
        User git
        IdentityFile ~.ssh/ssh-keys-user1

Host github-2
        HostName github.com
        User git
        IdentityFile ~.ssh/ssh-keys-user2
```

Of course, every repo within `~/Project1` is cloned via `git@github-1:author/repo.git` and every repo within `~/Project2` is cloned via `git@github-2:author/repo.git`.

Problem is: when I'm trying to push something while working in `~/Project2`, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Permission to author/repo.git denied to user1.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

which should not happen because, as I thought I did, everything within `~/Project2` should be related to `user2`, not `user1`. Everything else still works perfectly: I can pull, fetch, etc, but I cannot push.

How do I solve this?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but [this](https://gist.github.com/jexchan/2351996#gistcomment-522294) seems relevant.

Comment: @GoodDeeds I already have it like that: `[remote "origin"] url = git@github-user2:author/repo.git `, it's by default when cloning via `git clone git@github-2:author/repo.git`

Comment: @GoodDeeds I added that info in the OP too, thanks

Comment: Permission problem, not an auth problem, I think. If you can pull the repository but cannot push that means you don't have rights to push. Everything else look good.

Comment: @phd it is a permission problem, since git is trying to push something to a repo for `Project2` using `user1` (who has no access to such repo) instead of `user2` (who has indeed authorization to do so). So the point is: why is git using `user1` instead of `user2`?

Comment: Investigate: `cd ~/Project2/repo && git remote` — is it `git@github-2:author/repo.git`?

Comment: Yes, it is. And I've tried pushing to a repo I've created, so `author` is `user2`: still gets the error. But if I try to use HTTPS over SSH, `git push origin` works just fine, so I'm assuming is a SSH problem.

Comment: `ssh -Tv git@github-2:author/repo.git`

Comment: `debug1: resolve_canonicalize: hostname github-2:user2/repo.git is an unrecognised address \n
debug1: Connecting to github-2:user2/repo.git port 22. \n
ssh: Could not resolve hostname github-2:user2/repo.git: nodename nor servname provided, or not known`